# Detect repeating characters back to back Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a JavaScript calculator, and everything is finished, except there is one problem. when a user types in:

```
3**3 or 7++2
```

This brings up a parsing error - How do I detect if there are duplicates back to back?

If we look at the string `3+3+3*2`, that's gonna be safe to use, thought if we use the string `3++3+2`, that'd be flagged since the back-to-back **+**'s aren't allowed.

So, if there's ever two characters of the same **Type or Ascii value**, then flag that string as unsafe to use.

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML? How are we supposed to know how to detect back-to-back repeating characters when we have no information on how you're parsing the string? Do you want a regexp to detect any repeating characters? Then google for "javascript regexp backreference', and/or try `/(.)\1/`.

Comment: you should not do it this way even if regex works its just not the correct way of doing it. what if you want your calculator to have little complex expressions?. what you need is a parsing algorithm. first break your string into tokens and then use `recusive decent parsing` techinque. if you insist to use a simple way you can look for `shunting yard` algorithm. it might  take you sometime but you will be on right track.

Comment: basically the user presses a number on the the calculator , and the expression is returned in a string, and i use math.js to evaluate the string. It actually works surprisingly well for any calculations. But this was just for fun. ill take a look into that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last item in the console and if it's an operator then `return false`. Consider this:

```js
var operator = "/*+-^";
var arithmetic = "", lastItem;


 $("span").click(function(){
    // check if number is clicked    
      if($(this).hasClass("num")){
        $("#console").append($(this).text());
        arithmetic += $(this).text();
      }

      //get the last item on the console or in arithmetic string
    lastItem = arithmetic.substr(arithmetic.length-1, arithmetic.length);
    //check if last item is an operator, prevent click of an operator again
      if($(this).hasClass('operator')){
          if(operator.indexOf(lastItem) > -1){
            return false;
          }
          else{
              $("#console").append($(this).text());
              arithmetic += $(this).text();
          }

      }// end if --> checking operator ended.
    if($(this).hasClass('equal')){
         $("#result").append(eval(arithmetic));
          }
      
    });
```

```css
span{
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="num">1</span>
<span class="num">2</span>
<span class="num">3</span>
<span class="operator">+</span>
<span class="operator">*</span>
<span class="equal">=</span><br/><br/>

<div id="console"> </div> <br/>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```js
var regexp = /(\+\+|\-\-|\*\*)/;
regexp.test("22++33");
```

As per same suggestion you can easily get the match via regex.